Why does not Meld add blank lines?
The Meld diff tool explicitly states that it does not add extra blank lines.
To quote from documentation:
"When Meld shows differences between files, it shows both files as they would appear in a normal text editor. It does not insert additional lines so that the left and right sides of a particular change are the same size. There is no option to do this."
So if I compare the following two test files, i get something like

I find it much much more convenient to add blank lines, like KDoff3 does:

Actually it seems to me that almost every diffing tool does that, see for example Diffuse

To me this is really a show stopper (think about long files that have a lot of similar lines and a lot of "missing" lines) , but since I would like to stay in the GNOME ecosystem, I would like to know why Meld developers are so strict in this regard that they do not even have an option to enable that.
Is it a design choice or more that they did not have the time to implement it.
